# How should I distribute an OSX framework for use by developers of an application?

Tags: ios, macos, dependencies

Let's say I'm building an application with a dependency on a third party library, but one I've built myself - say, Boost. I've packaged the dependency into a framework which is the OSX way of doing things.

How should I now distribute the framework to the developers of the dependent application? If this were Windows I'd probably use Nuget, or apt etc on Ubuntu. Python has pip for this kind of thing - is there a standard MacOS way of dealing with combined source & binary dependencies?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine 3 different ways to do this:

- [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org): This it the nearest thing to something like a "package manager" as you get.
- Make a Github/Bitbucket Repository and use git for distribution
- make a framework bundle and distribute it via download (e.g. zipped or packed in a .dmg) or email